# Passing javascript value to php and back

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, parameter-passing

I am having some trouble with passing a javascript value to php and back.

The idea is that I have a form where a user fills out a postal code and is then (`onBlur`) presented with the correct street and city in two different input fields. The street and city are collected by POST method from an external php file (`getAddress.php`).

I know that the php script returns the correct values and the `complete()` function is called `onBlur`, but I don't know whether the value gets passed onto the php script and back.

**Javascript**

```
<script language="javascript">
    function complete() {
        var postalCode = document.getElementsByName("postalCode")[0].value;
        if(postalCode.length === 6) {
            var dataString = "postalCode=" + postalCode;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getAddress.php",
                dataType: "html",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(results) {
                    var json = JSON.parse(results);
                    document.getElementById("street").value = json.street;
                    document.getElementById("city").value = json.city;
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

**getAddress.php**

```
<?php

    $postalCode = $_POST['postalCode'];
    $postalCode = substr_replace($postalCode, ' ', 4, 0);
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM postalCodes WHERE postalCode="'.$postalCode.'"';
    $res = $con->query($sql);
    $res->data_seek(0);
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        $ID = $row['ID'];
        $street = $row['street'];
        $city = $row['city'];
        $results[] = array('ID' => $ID, 'street' => $street, 'city' => $city);
    }

    echo json_encode($results);

?>
```

**HTML**

```
<input name="postalCode" type="text" maxlength="6" onBlur="complete()" /><br />
<input name="street" id="street" type="text" disabled /><br />
<input name="number" type="text" maxlength="6" /><br />
<input name="city" id="city" type="text" disabled /><br />
```

Comment: You called the parameter to your "success" function "results", but then you call it "data" in the call to `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: @Pointy Sorry about that, but it stil doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please define your problem.

Comment: there is an SQL-injection problem in your query: you should escape the postalCode...

Comment: I would check out your browser console, most of em have a "network" tab that lets you inspect all http requests, responses, POST values, headers, etc.  You can check there to see if your values are being sent/received.

Comment: @James The POST values are correct, but the console in Chrome indicates that there is a 500 Internal Server Error when posting to getAddress.php

Comment: As an experiment, change `$_POST['postalCode']` to `$_REQUEST['postalCode']`, then fire up a new browser page and visit `yourURL/getAddress.php?postalCode=M5E%201W7`, see what error you get.

Comment: @James I am now getting the following responses, but the input fields stay blank `[{"ID":"171694","street":"Diemerkade","city":"Diemen"}]`

Comment: results is an array, the object within is results[0], the members of the object are results[0].street, etc.  Did you make the change that Manoj suggested?  You will need it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `dataType: "html",` to `dataType: "json",` and your `$results` is `array` so you need to use `index`

Try this:

```
function complete() {
    var postalCode = document.getElementsByName("postalCode")[0].value;
    if (postalCode.length === 6) {
        var dataString = "postalCode=" + postalCode;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getAddress.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(results) {
                document.getElementById("street").value = results[0].street;
                document.getElementById("city").value = results[0].city;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you are getting 500 internal server error message one of the reason can be that
`$con->query($sql)` is failing, make sure `$con` is initialized and `table` and `field` name are correct.

Comment: Your `$results` is `array` so you need to use `json[0].street` instead of `json.street`, answer updated

Comment: that is true, but in the case of large area postal codes that cover many streets, jamming "the first one I got" in the street field will annoy the user a little huh.  You would probably be best checking the count of how many responses you got, if it's one then fine use it, but don't do anything if you get more than one street for any given postal code.